# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array Soap API

Tags: magento-1.7, api, xml, soap, wsdl

This is my first time trying to pull information with the Magento soap API. I have used SOAP previously on the Orange M2M connect server.

Ive hit a stump and im not sure where to go from here. I have managed to pull salesOrderList from Magento and var_dump them, and all the data is there. But when i try to access say the increment_id using the method below i get this error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_soap_client\fulfilment\soap\class.orders.php

Code used to try and get the increment id:

```
$this->m_orders = $this->client->salesOrderList($this->sessionID);

foreach($this->m_orders as $o){
            var_dump($o['increment_id']);
        }
```

Why am i getting this error?

I haven't parsed the data through an XML Parser yet, do i need to before accessing the information? The reason i ask is because this is what i had to do when working with the orange m2m connect soap server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `$o` is not an array. It's an instance of `stdClass`. Try like this:

```
var_dump($o->increment_id);
```

or

```
var_dump((array)$o['increment_id']);
```

Comment: Excellent thanks, the first option worked perfectly. Just out of interest, whats the preferred method? Thanks

Comment: I prefer the first one. I try to use an object as it is. I don't cast it unless it's necessary